# How do I get the time elapsed between flags for every user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table below represents user logins (i.e `LogAction_INT = 1` is login, `LogAction_INT = 0` is logout). What is the best approach to sum the time elapsed between a user's login and logout (session). Ideally I need a total of time spent per user. Everything I can think of includes while loops and it's too complex.

```
ID  User_ID LogDate_DT  LogAction_INT
1940    18  2019-04-01 13:15:06.027 1
1941    18  2019-04-01 13:47:39.010 0
1942    18  2019-04-01 15:48:46.453 1
1943    18  2019-04-01 15:54:47.520 0
1944    68  2019-04-02 15:09:20.460 1
1945    68  2019-04-02 15:53:11.223 0
1946    86  2019-04-03 12:48:14.340 1
1947    86  2019-04-03 14:49:55.400 0
1948    80  2019-04-04 08:54:48.157 1
1949    86  2019-04-04 15:26:51.917 1
1950    86  2019-04-04 15:27:53.030 0
1951    86  2019-04-04 15:28:00.920 1
1952    86  2019-04-04 15:28:30.243 0
1953    86  2019-04-04 15:28:35.490 1
1954    86  2019-04-04 15:53:41.700 0
1955    68  2019-04-04 15:54:07.720 1
1956    80  2019-04-04 16:15:55.200 0
```

I expect to have something like:

```
User  TotalSessionTime
----  -----------------
18    04:45
68    10:02
80    06:12
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Are you really using sql server 2008? If so, you should consider upgrading. Official end of life is just a couple months away. For the question at hand, what do you expect as output from your sample data?

Comment: User_ID 68, has no logout value, in this case do we need to add any default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate each of the types and then use conditional aggregation or a join:

```
select user_id, seqnum,
       datediff(second, min(LogDate_DT), max(LogDate_DT)) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, LogAction_INT order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, seqnum;
```

You can then sum these by user:

```
select user_id, sum(diff_seconds)
from (select user_id, seqnum,
             datediff(second, min(LogDate_DT), max(LogDate_DT)) as diff_seconds
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by user_id, LogAction_INT order by id) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by user_id, seqnum;
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

The issue with this type of problem is that the ins and outs don't usually match up quite so cleanly.  That makes this a much harder problem.

In supported versions of SQL Server, I would do this using `lag()`.

Answer (score 1):

if it is always in pair, you can use row_number() to generate a running no and then group every 2 rows as 1

```
; with cte as
(
    select *, grp = (row_number() over (partition by User_ID order by ID) - 1) / 2
    from   your_table
)
cte2 as
(
    select  User_ID, elapsed = datediff(second, min(LogDate_DT), max(LogDate_DT))
    from    cte
    group by User_ID, grp
)
select User_ID, sum(elapsed)
from   cte2
group by User_ID
```

Comment: . . This is a fine answer; I prefer a simpler method for calculating what you call `grp`.